# Clojure - memoize on disk

Tags: caching, clojure, memoization

I would like to improve the performance of a function that returns resized images. The requested size of the images should not vary a lot (device-dependant), so it would make sense to somehow cache the results.

I could of course store it on disk, and check if the resized image exists, and make sure that if the original image is deleted, the resized versions are too...

Or, I could use a memoized function. But since the result are potentially quite big (an image is about 5 - 10 MB I think), it doesn't make sense to store those in memory (several tens of GB of images and their modified versions would fill up the memory quite quickly).

So, is there a way to have a memoized function that acts like the regular Clojure `defmemo`, but is backed by a folder in a local disk instead of memory ? I could then use a `ttl`strategy to make sure that images don't stay out of sync for too long.

Something similar to [crache](https://github.com/strongh/crache), but backed by a filesystem ?

Comment: You could store resized images in Redis or Memcached with some reasonable expiration to automatically cleanup unused records.

Comment: Just looked at your `crache` link and it looks perfect for your task.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Well crache is backed by Redis, which is an in-memory datastore. I don't have that much RAM unfortunately which is why I am trying to avoid that and have a filesystem instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Your filesystem as a cache is the right idea. If one file gets popular and the file is accessed a lot then your operating system will make sure it's in RAM. This is the same strategy many databases use. For instance Elasticsearch requires you to leave enough RAM to have the Lucene index files in RAM.

Don't modify your files ever either! Do it the functional way: Treat them as immutable data. Your input file shouldn't change. If it does then it's a new file. Hard disk space is increadibly cheap. Don't be afraid of having many files laying around. If you must, you can do a garbage collection which removes old/flagged files after a while.

To see if a file is in cache you simply check if the file exists. If it isn't: You write it once.

So to summarize:

- Let your O/S work the caching
- Don't edit your files. Treat them as immutable data. Write once
- Your O/S will free RAM of unused files. Hard disk space is super cheap.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on "immutable files" ?

Comment: An image file is an image file and shouldn't mutate. A resized file will always be the resized file of an input image file. Unless your resize algorithm changes there is no reason to re-write it. There is nothing wrong with having multiple different sizes on the disk. A naming convention for dimension is probably easiest. Filename == cache key

Comment: Right, that's the plan (I didn't even think in terms of immutable, since it's possible to delete them), but this will be achieved by a consistent naming scheme, right. +1 :) In the end I'll implement a core.cache with filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not implement a TTL-Cache from clojure.core.cache, wrapping it with the functionality you need? Your key can be whatever identifies your resized image, and the value would be its location on disk.  You could then implement some kind of a get-or-set! function, passing it the function that would be invoked to generate the image when it doesn't exist.
e.g.

```
(def Cache (atom (cache/ttl-cache-factory {} :ttl 20000)))

(defn get-or-update!
  "wraps the recommended has-hit-get pattern
   https://github.com/clojure/core.cache/wiki/Using"
  [key fn]
  (if (cache/has? @Cache key)
    (get (swap! Cache #(cache/hit % key)) key)
    (get (swap! Cache #(cache/miss % key (fn))) key)))
```

Comment: +1 nice snippet. Well that was more or less my original idea (I'm somewhat surprised nobody did this already, but that should be straightforward enough to implement). Now would the `ttl`information be persistent after a server reboot/update ? It doesn't matter with an atom, but it would with persistent data on disk.

Comment: I updated the snippet. No, and in that case you'd probably also want to write a function that generates the initial seed for the cache from the existing images on disk.  If maintaining the `ttl` information is important through reboots, it starts to get a little more complicated and you might have to look at extending core.cache or going with another solution.

Comment: This implementation is wrong. The state of your cache atom can change between the `cache/has` and the `cache/hit` or `cache/miss` function calls. Your implementation should look like this: `(get (swap! Cache #(if (cache/has? % key) (cache/hit % key) (cache/miss % (fn) key))))`

Comment: swap! may cause increase in call and can create spike in your application. It is better to use *core.memoize*. This will help during concurrent request. 
for better understanding please refer https://quanttype.net/posts/2020-10-25-caching-http-requests.html

Answer (score -1):

What you need sounds like a perfect use for Datomic.  It is easily used from Clojure, quite efficient, and like any good DB it has a least-recently-used (LRU) cache in memory.  It can also use a wide variety of backing databases as a substrate, from strictly in-memory (best for testing & experiments) to Postgres, Redis, DynamoDB, Riak, etc.  There is also a "dev" mode that uses local files for all storage.

See all of the details here:

- [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/)
- [Datomic "dev" mode](http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html#provisioning-dev-mode)

There is a standard version with a free, perpetual license that is suitable for most uses.  For advanced features a paid version is available.

Comment: Well that would add quite a bit of operational overhead wouldn't it? And correct me if I am wrong, but the cache is an in-memory cache, which is something I am trying to avoid?

Comment: The overhead will be very small.  Datomic uses a backing DB like Postgres that will store most of the data on disk.  Only recently used items will be in memory.

Comment: Well but now I have to deploy Datomic + Postgres.. Amazing technologies but that sound like overkill for storing images to me.

Comment: Added a link to the "dev" mode for local file storage above.

Comment: well thanks for the link I didn't think of that. I'm still a bit reluctant to introduce datomic (I'd be fine with just postgres for instance), but I'll definitely keep that in mind, that could come in handy later. So +1, but I'm still looking for a simple cache suggestion if anybody has one.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to stuff large images into a Datomic bytes attribute, realistically we're adding two or three layers between the application and the disc which aren't necessary for this usecase. Very large transactions don't play that well with the transactor in my experience.